# UIScrollView zoom to rect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I'm trying to zoom inside a UIScrollView by specifying a rect which is within scrollview's coordinates. However it's not working as expected. and I think it's because of zoom scale or maybe I'm missing a transformation. The scroll view I'm trying to zoom is from the Apple's example PhotoScroller -- ImageScrollView. Also I copied the code to generate a frame to zoom from Apple's example as well:

```
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    // The zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates.
    // At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the
    // imageScrollView's bounds.
    // As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible,
    // the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = scrollView.frame.size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = scrollView.frame.size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;
}
```

Now the code to actually zoom is the following:

```
CGPoint scrollRectCenter = CGPointMake(rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width /2) ,
                                       rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height / 2));
CGFloat newZoomScale = self.imageScrollView.zoomScale * 1.3f;
newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale);
CGRect zoomToRect = [self zoomRectForScrollView:self.imageScrollView withScale:newZoomScale withCenter:scrollRectCenter];
[self.imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomToRect animated:YES];
```

How can I zoom to a rect taking in consideration the zoomed imageView zoomscale, so that it fit's correctly?

What I'm trying to achieve is the effect of the photos app, in which the crop grid is moved and the scrollview zooms to that rect.

Does anybody know a link or code example to achieve a similar effect to the photos app? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess...you have implemented `- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale` delegate method.

Your problem occurs because when this method is called the scrollview's zoom scale is reseted to 1. I don't know why, don't ask me.

You can fix it in 2 ways :

1. you save the scale into a variable and in  `- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale` you set your variable to the appropriate scale and do the calculations with your scale.
2. You don't implement the bloody method, unless you have multiple views in your scrollview and each can zoom individually it doesn't worth it (after all you can access the zoom scale with `scrollview.zoomScale`)

If you don't implement the method disregard this answer :)